# Value of enum in xsl

Tags: java, xml, xslt, enums, jaxb

I am using java and I got an enum

```
public enum MyEnum {

    A("description of A"),
    B("description of B");

    private String description;

    MyEnum(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getBeschreibung();
    }

    public String getBeschreibung() { 
        return beschreibung;
    }

}
```

Furthermore i got a class which has the following member:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SomeValue {

    @XmlEnumValue(value = "myEnum")
    protected MyEnum myEnum;

}
```

with getter and setter, respectively. I got a generated xml-file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<someValue>
    <myEnum>A</myEnum>
</someValue>
```

My xsl looks like the following:

```
<xsl:for-each select="someValue">
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="myEnum" />
    </td>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Instead of gettin "A" i want "description of A". Can you tell me how to achieve this in my xsl-file? Is there some way to read the value of the enum?

Comment: Would you mind telling us what language that is in the first code block?

Comment: The `@XmlEnumValue` annotation is supposed to go on the `enum` constant declarations themselves, not on _uses_ of the enum type - `@XmlEnumValue("description of A") A("description of A")`, which would make JAXB produce the output you are after without having to do the mapping at the XSLT level.

Comment: The enum is out of my reach. I can't do any changes to it.

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using and how are you invoking it? If you're using something like Xalan via its Java API then you could implement an extension function to look up the description from the enum value, otherwise you're probably going to have to create an XML document with the name-to-description mapping and load that into your transformation with the `document` function.

Comment: Uhhh, i can't answer this question. This happens somewhere deep in our core implementations, which I have no access to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across the same problem and found this question but unfortunately with no answer. However after digging some more I found a solution for myself. It's a bit too late to answer a question after 5 years but hoping that if someone stumble on it again they might find it helpful -

First, import your `Enum` class at your `xsl` -

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:myEnum="xalan://path.to.your.package.MyEnum"/>
```

Then you need to write a static method at `MyEmum` class which will take `Enum` as value and `return` `Enum`'s `description`.

```
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public static String getEnumDescription(String enumVal) {
        return getEnumFromString(enumVal).getDescription();
}

private static MyEnum getEnumFromString(String enumVal) {
    for (MyEnum enum : MyEnum.values()) {
        if (enum.name() == enumVal) {
            return enum;
        }
    }

    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
}
```

Then you can call the static `getEnumDescription` method directly-

```
<td>
    <xsl:value-of select="myEnum:getEnumDescription(myEnum)" />
</td>
```